# Benefit of hardware with mobile access instead of wifi

Tags: mobile, arduino, raspberry-pi, wifi, hardware

What is the benefit of having mobile access over simply wifi with gateway hardware (such as Spark products or RaspberryPi)?

Thanks!#Kelsey

Answer (score 0):

You can proxy the network traffic, if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of mobile as I see it, is that mobile coverage is much more extensive and reliable than wifi.

The downside is that you need to pay for mobile traffic, it is slower, with lower bandwidth, and there is no advantage for devices that are in proximity to each other.

If you are doing home automation or some demo project for school/university, wifi would be fine.